List of important crypto paper
Sometimes there are paper like "New directions in cryptography" from W Diffie, M Hellman, that have a huge impact on cryptography and can be said to be important for the field. Can someone provide me a list of such paper?


Gentry's Fully Homomorphic Encryption Scheme has two versions;

over ideal lattices; Gentry's Thesis
over the integers; Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers


1991, Differential Cryptanalysis of DES-like Cryptosystems, Eli Biham and Adi Shamir

1992, A New Method for Known Plaintext Attack of FEAL Cipher (AKA Linear attack), Mitsuru Matsui and Atsuhiro Yamagishi

1996, Paul C. Kocher. Timing Attacks on Implementations of Diffie-Hellman, RSA, DSS, and Other Systems. CRYPTO 1996: 104–113

1997,  A fast new DES implementation in software (AKA Bit Slicing), Eli Biham.

2004, Cryptographic Hash-Function Basics: Definitions, Implications, and Separations for Preimage Resistance, Second-Preimage Resistance, and Collision Resistance by P. Rogaway and T. Shrimpton.

2005 - On Lattices, Learning with Errors, Random Linear Codes, and Cryptography,  Oded Regev, and earn the Gödel Prize in 2018.

2008 - On The Limits Of Quantum, Scott Aaronson


